# What's the easiest way to get the name of a file at a git commit level from its current name?

Tags: git, search, file-rename, revision-history

I'm working on a script that tracks and reports on some files in a repository to generate some internal metrics. I'm looping over the commit log for particular authors and using `git show <SHA1>:<filename>` to dump objects at various points in time and run them through the analyzer.

The trouble is, some of the files have been moved over time. I would like to generate the reports based on the current filenames, but I need to follow them across renames. It's easy enough to use `git log --follow` to get the history of a file, but what is the easiest command to use to fetch the old filename of a file at a certain commit hash based on its current name?

Comment: You shouldn't use `git show` in a script to begin with, because it's a porcelain command. You should use a plumbing command instead.

Comment: @Jubobs I'm open to redirection!

Comment: A difficulty is that git does not actually tracks renames - it tracks deletion and addition of potentially similar files. You'll probably have to find a commit where your current filename was added and somehow figure out which (hopefully similar) file was deleted in the same commit. This will however fail if a copy coexisted for a few commits...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I'm aware of how Git handles renames and you're right that it's full of pitfalls for this use, but there is hope — a) I want it to fail in the event of co-existing similar files and b) the `log --follow` does follow the rename path I want to track, so whatever that did I just want access to the filename it comes up with but to query it at a point in time based on the current name.

Comment: Good point - then you can use `git log --follow --pretty=format:"%H" -- <filename>` to get all the commit-hashes involved, but I don't know how to obtain the determined filename...

Comment: ...and then you could probably parse `git show <sha> | grep "^diff.*<lastknownfilename>"` to track the filename yourself. Though you could skip the `git log --follow` part then...

Comment: You can parse the output of e.g. `git diff --name-stat  prev..next`, which will contain entries such as `A  newfilename` and `D oldfilename`